# JPA Entity and HQL JOIN command

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to achieve something like sql command below by using HQL and JPA.
Instead of "SELECT user_id..." I need SELECT OBJECT(o).

```
SELECT user_id FROM posix_user o INNER JOIN postgre_user n ON n.id=o.user_id WHERE n.name='USERNAME2'
```

I have some problems with this part of the code in JPA DAO:

```
public List<PosixUserEntity> listPosixUsers(final String uid_number) {


final StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("SELECT OBJECT(o) FROM ");
   queryString.append(this.entityClass.getSimpleName());
   queryString.append(" o JOIN com.services.dao.user.jpa.UserEntity n ON (n.id=o.user_id) WHERE n.name LIKE :uid_number");

 final Query findByNameQuery = entityManager.createQuery(queryString.toString()).setParameter("uid_number", uid_number);

   return findByNameQuery.getResultList();
    }
```

**JOIN ON** is not allowet here and I did not know how to replace it.
Also how can I replace **com.services.dao.user.jpa.UserEntity** by something cleaner.

There is my Entites, they may need to be improved:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posix_user")
public class PosixUserEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private String user_id;

@Column(name = "uid_number")
private String uid_number;

@Column(name = "home_directory")
private String home_directory;

@Column(name = "login_shell")
private String login_shell;

@Column(name = "group_id")
private String group_id;

//getters,setters....

@Entity
@Table(name = "postgre_user")
@SQLDelete(sql = "update postgre_user set status = 'removed' where id = ?")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private UserStatus status;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "usertype")
    private String userType;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserRoleTargetGroupEntity> userRoleTargetGroupEntity;

    @Column(name = "last_login")
    private String lastLogin;

    @Column(name = "previous_login")
    private String previousLogin;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "change_password_flag")
    private Boolean userPasswordResetFlag;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private PosixUserEntity posixUserEntity;
```

You may also need to know that **FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES postgre_user (id)** - it should look like that

Can you know how can I modify my SELECT?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? Joining unrelated entities was added in 5.1.0, https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16

Comment: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4 but I cannot change it.

Comment: You cannot join between unrelated entities in Hibernate 4.x. You will either need to make two selects or add a relationship to your Entity classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested a simplified version of your classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posix_user")
public class PosixUserEntity {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "user_id")
     private Long user_id;

     // getter + setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "postgre_user")
public class UserEntity {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     private String name;

     @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
     private PosixUser posixUserEntity;

     // getter + setter
}
```

And this JPQL query works as expected

```
 String jpql = "SELECT p " 
              + "FROM UserEntity n JOIN n.posixUserEntity p " 
              + "WHERE n.name LIKE :uid_number)";
```

**JOIN** is allowed because you have mapped the relationship in `UserEntity`.
and you don't need to specify the complete name of your entity class.
Check if it has been included when you define your persistence unit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Before I had, a "Private Long id" instead of  "Private String id". I tested similar way but I dad problem with Entites. Great thanks.